# Sed - changes in multiple files on Mac OSX

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I would like to add some text to the end of some specific files. If I do this however:

```
[command producing file names] | xargs sed -e '$s/$/\
TEXT/'
```

I get the following result:

```
(all the contents of every single matching file)
TEXT
```

This is obviously not what I want. Adding `g` to the substitution pattern does not help either and turning on `-i` results only the last file being edited.

Is there anything I can do to fix this or an alternative to add a specific string to the end of a list of files?

Comment: Why not just append? `echo STUFF >> FILE`

Comment: @usr that adds TEXT after every single line. I want one per file.

Comment: may be you need `-s` option as well? but I thought using `-i` option automatically enabled `-s` as well.. and I'm not sure if `-s` is available on macos sed

Comment: Are you trying to modify the original files or output the contents of those files with some extra test appended to each or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to add a line to a set of files, keep it simple and just write a line to the end of each file:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    printf '%s\n' 'TEXT' >> "$file"
done < <(command producing file names)
```

or you could still use xargs if you prefer:

```
command producing file names |
xargs -I {} sh -c 'printf '\''%s\n'\'' '\''TEXT'\'' >> {}'
```

Comment: Process substitution + read is not exactly the simplest way I can imagine. :) I like it though.

Comment: It's printing a list of file names, reading them one at a time and printing new text to the end of each file - feel free to come up with a simpler way but I can't think of one that'd be robust (work for any contents of TEXT) and portable (work for any version of the tools being used). I added a robust, portable xargs solution but IMHO it's not simpler.

Answer (score 0):

My teammate told me a working solution: adding `-n 1` to `xargs` actually fixes this.

```
[command producing file names] | xargs -n 1 sed -e '$s/$/\
TEXT/'
```

Comment: unless `TEXT` contains `&` or `\1` or `/` or .... Using sed just to append a line introduces unnecessary complications and portability issues.

Comment: Maybe it does, but I wanted to know how to fix those portability issues on Mac :) As I am new to Mac I find suprising that "sed" and the ports of the gnu tools behave a little bit different.

Comment: The GNU tools don't behave different, it's just that the default tools are BSD, not GNU.